# Make elements of an array extend the return type of the previous element

Tags: typescript-generics

I have an array of functions, and i want each function in the array to extend the CTX type for any length,
here is an example:

```
[
  (ctx: CTX) => T1,
  (ctx: CTX & T1) => T2,
  (ctx: CTX & T1 & T2) => T3,
  ...etc
]
```

I would like to know a type that can do something like this, I'm not sure myself how to do something like this.

EDIT 1: Here is an example use case

```
export default api()
.use([redis, loggedIn])
.get([getUser, getGuild], (req,res,ctx) => {

  // ctx would be: {
  //   redis: IORedis, 
  //   token: string,
  //   session: string,
  //   user: IUser,
  //   guild: IGuild
  // }

})
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are asking.  If you literally want an array type that could accept _any_ length of parameters, it would be an infinitely long type.  Also, even if you limited it, how would TS now what the previous members types were before they were instantiated?  Could you perhaps provide an example of how you would intend to use this type (ideally with a playground link)?  That may help folks understand what you are looking for.

Comment: I added an example of how i would be using it.